# How to get fonts CharterBT and MathDesignCH?

Tags: fonts

Many of the documents I need for research use the following fonts for displaying math equations:

```
CharterBT 
MathDesignCH
```

Where to get it from? If it is not free, is there any alternative free fonts that would work?

Answer (score 0):

[STIX Fonts](http://www.stixfonts.org/) is a free font designed for science and mathematics.

Comment: I've looked through the current STIX Fonts download off their sourceforge page, as part of the current attempts to improve low quality posts - this answer was autoflagged as such - and I can't seem to find the fonts in question. Could you perhaps update your answer with which download/location may have these fonts?

Comment: @Journeyman: Done.

Comment: Oh, i wasn't complaining about the shortness. I can't find the fonts in question in their most recent download - they're all STIX(description)-(Bold/italic/regular).

Comment: @Journeyman: "... is there any alternative free fonts that would work?"

Comment: Ahh, ok - It wasn't very clear, least to me